# Setting fixed Windows height and width in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I tried setting window width and height but it doesn't work

[image]

When I used Screen.currentResolution and screenWidth or screenHeight it shows different values

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure that it works on Android phones. Perhaps, this option is for android devices like tv-boxes.

Why are you even trying to do this? Maybe, there is another solution for you issue.

Comment: IIRC, this is the intended behaviour. I've not tried to set the resolution from the editor but when you set it from a script the values of Screen.width and height remain the same as the original resolution.